# Rails 3 Select Menu Default Value when editing an Entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, select

I am using the following code for a select menu in my rails app

Controller:

```
@discount_options = {'% Off' => 'percent', '$ Off' => 'dollar', '$ For' => 'flat', 'Free with Purchase Of' => 'bonus', 'Buy One Get One Free' => 'bogo' }
```

View (within a form_for)

```
<%= f.select :discount, options_for_select(@frugle_discount_options) %>
```

This works just fine when creating a new record.  If I come back to edit this record, it always ends up defaulting to the first one "% Off"

I find it surprisingly hard to find good documentation online about select menus.. can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work, because it looks to me like what you wrote should be OK.  I would point out that, unless you're in Ruby 1.9.x, hashes are not guaranteed to return items in any particular order, so you should probably use a nested array for your options instead of a hash.  `[['% Off', 'percent'], ['$ Off', 'dollar'], ...`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass second parameter in

```
options_for_select_method(@discount_options, 'bonus')
```

You can set it by using :discount parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should make a reference to the f.object with :selected

```
    <%= f.select :discount, options_for_select(@frugle_discount_options), :selected => f.object.discount %>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `:selected => f.object.discount` actually go inside as the last argument in `options_for_select` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great blog post I came across that discusses the use of the various select helpers in rails. Worth a read.

http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails